# WebRTC ScreenCapturerAndroid

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, screen-capture

I'm trying to create a screen capturer app for android. I already have the webRTC portion setup with a video capturer using Camera2Enumerator library from [here](https://amryousef.me/android-webrtc). How can I modify this to create a pre-recorded video capturer instead of camera capturer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to give an update that I have solved this. I'm unable to share the entire code but here's a process that might help:

1. Acquire one frame of your pre-recorded file and store in a byte array(must be in YUV format)
2. Replace the VideoCapturer() with the following:

   ```
   fun onGetFrame(p0: ByteArray?) {

       var timestampNS = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())

       var buffer:NV21Buffer = NV21Buffer(p0,288,352,null)

       var videoFrame:VideoFrame = VideoFrame(buffer,0,timestampNS)

       localVideoSource.capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame)

       videoFrame.release()

   }
   ```

   where p0 is the byte array with the frame
3. Call this function in startLocalVideoCapture() using a timer (every few milliseconds...I used 10 nanoseconds) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer
4. remove this line in startLocalVideoCapture()--->

   ```
   VideoCapturer.initialize(
               surfaceTextureHelper,
               localVideoOutput.context,
               localVideoSource.capturerObserver)
   ```